# Is the V_t in this document regular Thermal voltage?

Tags: transistors, thermal, non-linear

I have been looking at this short document.

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c490/4c04a7be1d675e360409178da71a1253f6d8.pdf

It uses V_t and defines it as thermal voltage of a transistor.

It does not make so much sense to me though, as input to such a filter will be audio peak values of +-0.9V. And that input is fed into a tanh() function wherein its divided by 2*V_t, so if V_t is 0.026V it like multiplying it with 19.23 before taking tanh() of it. That will completely saturate the tanh() function, and no good audio will come out. See equation 13 for that.

So is the paper using a different definition of V_t in this paper?

PS: Sorry for posting this here, but I think this is an electronics question more than a DSP question.

Comment: Yes, it is. Maybe your assumption of the input voltage is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I think its correct. But after rereading the paper again, I start to think that the input voltage to the difference equations (like x(n)) is actually the voltage over the capacitors. So I need to find a way to translate from input voltage to the voltage over the capacitor in the first stage. No idea how to do that though.
So in this image it would be from V_in to deltaV_1:
https://s19.postimg.cc/lm3wcr2wj/ladder.png